# IndexOutOfBoundsException when clicking Spinner

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have a Spinner set with a custom ArrayAdapter.  It looks like the data is properly updated, as I can see the first item in the spinner has text. But when I click the spinner I get the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: net.estebanrodriguez.anecdotals, PID: 4741
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:390)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:415)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(AppCompatSpinner.java:651)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(AppCompatSpinner.java:645)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner.compatMeasureContentWidth(AppCompatSpinner.java:567)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropdownPopup.computeContentWidth(AppCompatSpinner.java:772)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropdownPopup.show(AppCompatSpinner.java:798)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner.performClick(AppCompatSpinner.java:437)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Here is the adapter code:

```
    private class SettingsSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Institution> {

    List<Institution> institutions;

    public SettingsSpinnerAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, List<Institution> institutions) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.institutions = institutions;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return institutions.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.settings_spinner_item, parent, false);
        }
        String institutionName = institutions.get(position).getName();
        TextView textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id._setting_spinner_item_text);
        textView.setText(institutionName);
        return convertView;
    }

    public void addAll(List<Institution> institutions) {
        this.institutions = institutions;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
}
```

Here is the spinner setup in my fragment:

```
    private void setUpSpinner(){

    adapter = new SettingsSpinnerAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.settings_spinner_item, institutions);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Institution institution = institutions.get(position);
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString(Institution.KEY, institution.getRemoteId()).apply();
            FocusHolder.getInstance().setInstitutionFocus(institutions.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}
```

Here is where the data gets updated:

```
    private void subscribeToLiveData(){
    livedata.observe(this, viewState -> {

        if(viewState.getInstitutions() != null){
            institutions = viewState.getInstitutions();
            adapter.addAll(institutions);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: That's kind of an incomplete `ArrayAdapter` subclass. When the `Spinner` tries to create a dropdown `View`, it's accessing `ArrayAdapter`'s private, internal `List`, which is empty because you never pass it anything, since you have your own. You really don't need a subclass for what you're doing there. Instead, you could override `toString()` in your `Institution` class to return the name, and then just do `new ArrayAdapter<Institution>(context, R.layout.settings_spinner_item, R.id._setting_spinner_item_text)`. Then, instead of your `addAll()`/`notifyDataSetChanged()`, do `clear()`/`addAll()`.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks I just realized it. I updated the addAll in my spinner to include super.addAll(institutions);  I would use the simpler version you suggest, but I need the toString of institution to give me more information for logging purposes.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, you don't really need the subclass at all, but if you're intent on keeping it, I would mention that that's probably not what you want to do. Your original implementation of that method just replaced the `List`. Calling the `super` method there will just add the new `List` to whatever was there before. Additionally, you now have two separate `List`s; yours, and the one that `ArrayAdapter` is keeping internally. It would be better if you just got rid of the subclass. You could create a separate method to return your logging info. Otherwise, subclass `BaseAdapter` instead.

Comment: I followed your advice.  It's much simpler.  Thanks for the assist, Mike!